# How to replicate a "Ctrl+F5" page reload in JxBrowser

Tags: browser-cache, jxbrowser

We have a generated HTML-File on the local filesystem containing some images living on remote server. This HTML-file is being displayed by JxBrowser.

When the images are being changed by our Java Application those images won't update because of clientside caching.

Our most preferred solution would be to offer some sort of "Ctrl+F5"-action by which the enduser itself could clear the cache only for this HTML-file and its resources.

Is there a way to do this with JxBrowser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `reloadIgnoringCache()` method of the Browser instance.